# General optimization - implementation in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, gradient

I am currently struggling with a gradient descent implementation problem, more on the math side of it. I have a matrix of input values, for example - `[[1,1,0,2],[2,3,5,1],[2,1,8,0]]`. I want to calculate weights which will minimize the error against output vector, the minimized function is standard linear model so my hypothesis is minimize -> `np.dot(input,weights)-y`. The problem is - values of weight vector should add to specific number, say 2. Also vector of outputs is normalized such as `np.dot(input,weights)/sum(np.dot(input,weights))` - this result is then compared to a desired output vector. How should I define this task in python/numpy?

Example of human-tuned procedure:

1) input matrix 
`[[4,0,2,0,2,0],[2,0,0,2,2,0],[2,0,0,2,2,0],[4,0,2,0,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,2],[0,4,0,0,0,2],[0,2,0,0,0,2],[0,2,2,0,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,2],[4,0,2,0,0,0]]`

2) desired output `[12.94275893,8.07054252,9.281123898,10.53654162,8.698251382,14.67643103,7.158870124,10.26752354,8.324615155,10.0433418]`

3) weights which transform input vectors in such way that np.dot(input,weights)/sum(np.dot(input,weights)) are okay
`[11,21,18,0,20,14]`- sum fixed at 84

4) the final output, reasonably deviated from 2) `[15.15,7.83,7.83,10.10,8.08,14.14,8.84,9.85,8.08,10.10]`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. ```The problem is - values of weight vector should add to specific number, say 2``` What does it mean? And why should normalization matter? Usually you are fitting a normalizer which is then ready to transform new data. Also: is this for research/learning-purposes? Because there is a lot of good software doing this for you.

Comment: I meant that my weights are fixed in their sum - the sum of those values should be exactly 2.

Comment: That sounds like an **np-hard** problem then which is infeasible to solve in general! It's also no more a convex-optimization problem. Of course you could get an approximate solution adding a penalty-term which is active on the deviations in regards to this value. But well.. still non-convex i think (which would mean: very hard to optimize). **Edit:** Maybe my feeling was wrong. It should be convex if using a penalty-term.

Comment: and this is for bioinformatics research - I didnt want to flood my post with biology, it often just complicates the heart of the problem. Now it is solved in excel sheet by guessing the appropriate values with approximate solutions. I wonder if is there better approach

Comment: Gradient-descent is usually used within nonconstrained optimization so you might need to use some penalty-methods. It would be easy to formulate a Quadratic Program, penalizing the deviation like recommended above.

Comment: Thanks for a hint! Can you recommend some reading? I am new to optimization

Comment: Well... general optimization stuff: [Numerical Optimization](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2v9mZ7brPAhXnDsAKHUp7D1AQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.agh.edu.pl%2F~pba%2Fpdfdoc%2FNumerical_Optimization.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHu3vTW_9j2cH6iLMdUrAsbUNBiQQ&sig2=_0d06mxXwEBnIgjheqv1VA) (a lot of stuff on penalty-methods there). If you want to **try** the QP-approach: have a look at [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/) (assuming you can formulate it as **convex optimization problem**).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the scale of your example data, here is the solution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

a = np.array([[1,1,0,2],[2,3,5,1],[2,1,8,0]], dtype=float)
target = np.random.randn(3)
target /= target.sum()

def f(p):
    p = np.r_[p, 2 - p.sum()]
    res = a.dot(p)
    res /= res.sum()
    return res - target

r, _ = optimize.leastsq(f, np.zeros(3))
print(target)
print(np.r_[r, 2 - r.sum()])
```

output:

```
[-0.21987606  0.70869974  0.51117632]
[ 2.15713915  7.47554671  0.38959227 -8.02227813]
```

Here is the code for your real data:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

a = np.array([[4,0,2,0,2,0],
              [2,0,0,2,2,0],
              [2,0,0,2,2,0],
              [4,0,2,0,0,0],
              [0,0,2,0,0,2],
              [0,4,0,0,0,2],
              [0,2,0,0,0,2],
              [0,2,2,0,0,0],
              [0,0,2,0,0,2],
              [4,0,2,0,0,0]], dtype=float)

target = np.array([12.94275893,8.07054252,9.281123898,10.53654162,8.698251382,
                   14.67643103,7.158870124,10.26752354,8.324615155,10.0433418])

target /= target.sum()

def make_vector(x):
    return np.r_[x, 84 - x.sum()]

def calc_target(x):
    res = a.dot(make_vector(x))
    res /= res.sum()
    return res

def error(x):
    return calc_target(x) - target

x, _ = optimize.leastsq(error, np.zeros(a.shape[1] - 1))
print(make_vector(x))
print(calc_target(x) * 100)
print((calc_target(x) - target) * 100)
```

the output:

```
[  9.40552097  20.32874298  19.8199082   13.13991088  10.00062863
  11.30528834]
[ 12.90025777   8.63333209   8.63333209  10.2474406    8.25642656
  13.78390749   8.39140263  10.65003363   8.25642656  10.2474406 ]
[-0.04250116  0.56278957 -0.64779181 -0.28910102 -0.44182483 -0.89252354
  1.23253251  0.38251009 -0.0681886   0.2040988 ]
```

It seems that the problem can also be solve by `numpy.linalg.lstsq()`, but it need to simplify your problem to a linear euqations.

Comment: OP is struggling with the math side, and definitely seems like somebody who wants to learn. I'd suggest adding some explanation for future readers, after all Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Thank for your response! I will test it on the bigger dataset and let you know. As Andras mentioned I will also appreciate any theoretical insights.

Comment: There are some assumptions/model-decisions hidden in this code (loss + penalty minimized jointly with 1.0 pentalty-factor?) and it would be really great to mention these. And even a (in my opinion) numpy-aware (non guru-) user struggles when seeing something like ```np_r_```. Nonetheless: interesting code.

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to mention that solution is not supposed to have negative values. Let me paste the example of manually tuned input/otput: